# Laravel Collection trying to get property 'vote' of non-object

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

It's not a duplicate question, I've tried most solutions that I found so far in StackOverflow.

I have a Controller passing a Laravel Collection to a view like so:

```php
$votes = Vote::where('spid', '=', $id)->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get()->keyBy('comment_id');
```

which generates something like:

```php
 App\Vote Object 
( [attributes:protected] => Array ( [id] => 2 [comment_id] => 13 [user_id] => 1 [vote] => 1 [spid] => 101190045 ) )
```

(There are also other attributes like `incrementing` or `keyType`, but they were all ommitted).

When I use something like this in a view, however,

```php
{{$votes->get($comment->id)->vote}}
```

I get:

```php
Trying to get property 'vote' of non-object
```

When I try

```php
{{$votes->get($comment->id)['vote']}}
```

I get:

```php
Trying to access array offset on value of type null
```

I'm certain that the passed `$votes` is valid, because when I do a `{{($votes->get($comment->id)->vote))}}` in the view, I get `{"id":2,"comment_id":13,"user_id":1,"vote":1,"spid":101190045}`.

When I also do a `dd($votes->get($comment->id)->vote)`, strangely enough, it returns the correct value.

Comment: I'm assuming `{{$votes->get($comment->id)->vote}}` is inside a `@foreach` loop? Maybe some of your `$comment->id` are not inside your `$votes` Object

Comment: Read the documentation of [keyBy](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-keyby) and its usage, it will become clearer. Your key in collection becomes category ID and you don’t need to use get method to fetch by it. Use plain [].

Comment: @ChristopheHubert Yes, it's inside a foreach loop. If there is no `$votes->get($comment->id)`, how would I "catch" that if that value is null?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Christophe Hubert, I realized that it's in a `foreach` loop, and some of the results were returning `null`. I just did

```
{{$votes->get($comment->id)->vote ?? 0}}
```